# Compare two datatables, if anything is different show MessageBox

Tags: vb.net

I have two datatables, one of them is populated when application starts and the other one is populated on button click. How can i check (fastest way) if anything changed in second datatable?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
For Each row1 As DataRow In dtt.Rows
  For Each row2 As DataRow In dtt1.Rows
    Dim array1 = row1.ItemArray
    Dim array2 = row2.ItemArray

    If array1.SequenceEqual(array2) Then
    Else
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: You could use the DataTables own change tracking features to see which rows were modifed/added/deleted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loops are nested. This means that the inner  For Each loops through each row of `dtt1` for each single row of `dtt`. This is not what you want. You want to loop the two tables in parallel. You can do so by using the enumerators that the `For Each` statements use internally

```
Dim tablesAreDifferent As Boolean = False
If dtt.Rows.Count = dtt1.Rows.Count Then
    Dim enumerator1 = dtt.Rows.GetEnumerator()
    Dim enumerator2 = dtt1.Rows.GetEnumerator()

    Do While enumerator1.MoveNext() AndAlso enumerator2.MoveNext()
        Dim array1 = enumerator1.Current.ItemArray
        Dim array2 = enumerator2.Current.ItemArray
        If Not array1.SequenceEqual(array2) Then
            tablesAreDifferent = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Else
    tablesAreDifferent = True
End If
If tablesAreDifferent Then
    'Display message
Else
    '...
End If
```

The enumerators work like this: They have an internal cursor that is initially placed before the first row. Before accessing a row through the `Current` property, you must move to it with the `MoveNext` function. This function returns the Boolean `True` if it succeeds, i.e. as long as there are rows available.

Since now we have a single loop statement and advance the cursors of `enumerator1` and `enumerator2` at each loop, we can compare corresponding rows.

---

Note that the `Rows` collection implements `IEnumerable` and thus the enumerators returned by `GetEnumerator` are not strongly typed. I.e. `Current` is typed as `Object`. If instead you write

```
Dim enumerator1 = dtt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).GetEnumerator()
Dim enumerator2 = dtt1.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).GetEnumerator()
```

Then you get enumerators of type `IEnumerator(Of DataRow)` returning strongly typed `DataRow`s.